# .coredumpctl pid weird alignment

Tags: systemd, gdb

While starting my first use of coredumpctl, I have noticed a repeated occurrence of a bug. I have created a small snippet which contains a stack BOF vulnerability (compiled with no stack protection). I executed the program with long enough input (simple AAAAAAA...), and as expected I got SegFault.

While trying to find the dump with coredumpctl, I have noticed that the PID of in the listing command is always with value 3 less than the one which I should try to use while matching.

If that wasn't clear, I ran the list command I got:

```
TIME                            PID   UID   GID SIG COREFILE  EXE
Tue 2020-03-03 15:29:23 XDD    3681  1000  1000  11 present   /path/to/binary/
```

But when trying to read the dump I get:

```
$ coredumpctl debug _PID=<tab_pressed>
3684
```

Which happens again and again, always with positive 3 alignment for the debug command.

This bug isn't preventing me from working but it is still a strange phenomenon, which I would like to know more about. If there is some interesting explanation for why this is happening I would be very interested to know.

System Info:

Ubuntu 19.10(eoan)

Linux kernel - 5.3.0-40-generic.

gdb - version 8.3

systemd - version 242

If more information is needed let me know and I will edit the post.
Thanks a lot in advance for all the helpers.